# Bitex - Cryptocurrency Exchange API Framework for Python

Tags: python, rest, modules, cryptocurrency

[BitEx](https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/bitex/tree/dev) is a Python module I've been working on for a little over 9 months now, as a side project. It was published 6 months ago on GitHub, and as I edge closer to my 1.0 release, I wanted to take the opportunity to present my code on here, in order to straighten it out.

### What it solves and offers

It's designed to eliminate the need to get into the gory details of REST APIs of crypto exchanges, and offer a homogeneous and intuitive interface for all supported APIs. It takes care of authentication procedures, and offers a standardized set of methods (with identical method signature) for all commonly used methods at an exchange (polling order book & tickers, placing and cancelling orders, amongst others), as well as all other specific methods (or as many as I had the time to implement thus far).

It comes, essentially, as two sub packages: `bitex.api` is the backend taking care of setting up http requests via the `requests` module, as well as handling authentication specifics. It can be seen as wrapper for `requests` and technically could be used all on its own to send and receive data to/from exchanges.

The other is `bitex.interfaces`, which offers the above mentioned homogenous, standardized methods for all implemented exchanges. In addition to offering identical method signatures, it also aims to standardize method's return values. As these can differ significantly from exchange to exchange, these methods take care of data formatting, via the help of formatters found in `bitex.formatters` and the `return_json` decorator.
It relies on `bitex.api`.

### Why I am submitting this for review

Ever since I started this project, I've rewritten the base code several times significantly. It took me a long time to figure out how to lay out the structure (which is mostly due to my learning curve over the past year as a first year software development apprentice).

Over the past two months, however, I've become rather fond and proud of the current structure and deem it quite presentable - enough so, to have it publicly audited.

I have read the meta question on [how to get the best value out of my review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions), and quite initially settled on having three 'rounds' of reviews for my code:

1. Code style (PEP8, readability, pythonic-ness).
2. Refactoring Options and the evaluation of present layout, especially API class' `sign()` method, `return_json()` decorator and usage of formatter funcs.
3. Flaws, improvements in code and logic, bugs, etc.

### Review Round 1: code style

I have especially my worries about the `bitex.api` sub-module. The `sign()` method is difficult to generalize as it is since the inputs vary massively, forcing me to pass everything to them. It turned out ok to *me* - but I'm not sure how to make this readable for normal people (that is, everyone but me).

The counter-question, of course, is if I even have to worry about readability in those classes - they're not primarily intended to be used as standalone objects, although I do not explicitly deny access to them.

I am aware that docstrings aren't present in methods for classes - I'm on this, it's just that writing docstrings isn't very exciting (albeit I know of their importance).

### `bitex.api`

```
>>bitex.api.api
# Import Built-Ins
import logging
import requests
import time
# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class RESTAPI:

    def __init__(self, uri, api_version='', key='', secret=''):
        """
        Base Class for REST API connections.
        """
        self.key = key
        self.secret = secret
        self.uri = uri
        self.apiversion = api_version
        self.req_methods = {'POST': requests.post, 'PUT': requests.put,
                            'GET': requests.get, 'DELETE': requests.delete,
                            'PATCH': requests.patch}
        log.debug("Initialized RESTAPI for URI: %s; "
                  "Will request on API version: %s" %
                  (self.uri, self.apiversion))

    def load_key(self, path):
        """
        Load key and secret from file.
        """
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.key = f.readline().strip()
            self.secret = f.readline().strip()

    def nonce(self):
        return str(int(1000 * time.time()))

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Dummy Signature creation method. Override this in child.
        URL is required to be returned, as some Signatures use the url for
        sig generation, and api calls made must match the address exactly.
        """
        url = self.uri

        return url, {'params': {'test_param': "authenticated_chimichanga"}}

    def query(self, method_verb, endpoint, authenticate=False,
              *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Queries exchange using given data. Defaults to unauthenticated query.
        """
        request_method = self.req_methods[method_verb]

        if self.apiversion:
            endpoint_path = '/' + self.apiversion + '/' + endpoint
        else:
            endpoint_path = '/' + endpoint

        url = self.uri + endpoint_path
        if authenticate:  # sign off kwargs and url before sending request
            url, request_kwargs = self.sign(url, endpoint, endpoint_path,
                                            method_verb, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            request_kwargs = kwargs
        log.debug("Making request to: %s, kwargs: %s" % (url, request_kwargs))
        r = request_method(url, timeout=5, **request_kwargs)
        log.debug("Made %s request made to %s, with headers %s and body %s. "
                  "Status code %s" %
                  (r.request.method, r.request.url, r.request.headers,
                   r.request.body, r.status_code))
        return r


>>bitex.api.rest
# Import Built-ins
import logging
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import time
import urllib
import urllib.parse
from requests.auth import AuthBase

# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew
from bitex.api.api import RESTAPI


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class BitfinexREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://api.bitfinex.com'):
        super(BitfinexREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                           key=key, secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            req = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            req = {}
        req['request'] = endpoint_path
        req['nonce'] = self.nonce()

        js = json.dumps(req)
        data = base64.standard_b64encode(js.encode('utf8'))

        h = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf8'), data, hashlib.sha384)
        signature = h.hexdigest()
        headers = {"X-BFX-APIKEY": self.key,
                   "X-BFX-SIGNATURE": signature,
                   "X-BFX-PAYLOAD": data}

        return url, {'headers': headers}


class BitstampREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, user_id='', key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://www.bitstamp.net/api'):
        self.id = user_id
        super(BitstampREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                           key=key, secret=secret)

    def load_key(self, path):
        """
        Load key and secret from file.
        """
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.id = f.readline().strip()
            self.key = f.readline().strip()
            self.secret = f.readline().strip()

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        message = nonce + self.id + self.key

        signature = hmac.new(self.secret.encode(), message.encode(),
                             hashlib.sha256)
        signature = signature.hexdigest().upper()

        try:
            req = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            req = {}
        req['key'] = self.key
        req['nonce'] = nonce
        req['signature'] = signature
        return url, {'data': req}


class BittrexREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1.1',
                 url='https://bittrex.com/api'):
        super(BittrexREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                          secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}

        nonce = self.nonce()

        req_string = endpoint_path + '?apikey=' + self.key + "&nonce=" + nonce + '&'
        req_string += urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        headers = {"apisign": hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'),
                                       (self.uri + req_string).encode('utf-8'),
                                       hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()}

        return self.uri + req_string, {'headers': headers, 'params': {}}


class CoincheckREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='api',
                 url='https://coincheck.com'):
        super(CoincheckREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                            key=key, secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):

        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}

        params = json.dumps(params)
        # sig = nonce + url + req
        data = (nonce + endpoint_path + params).encode('utf-8')
        h = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf8'), data, hashlib.sha256)
        signature = h.hexdigest()
        headers = {"ACCESS-KEY": self.key,
                   "ACCESS-NONCE": nonce,
                   "ACCESS-SIGNATURE": signature}

        return url, {'headers': headers}


class GdaxAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key, passphrase):
        self.api_key = api_key.encode('utf-8')
        self.secret_key = secret_key.encode('utf-8')
        self.passphrase = passphrase.encode('utf-8')

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        message = (timestamp + request.method + request.path_url +
                   (request.body or ''))
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
        signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())

        request.headers.update({
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
            'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
        return request


class GDAXRest(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, passphrase='', key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://api.gdax.com'):
        self.passphrase = passphrase
        super(GDAXRest, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                       secret=secret)

    def load_key(self, path):
        """
        Load key and secret from file.
        """
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.passphrase = f.readline().strip()
            self.key = f.readline().strip()
            self.secret = f.readline().strip()

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        auth = GdaxAuth(self.key, self.secret, self.passphrase)
        try:
            js = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            js = {}

        return url, {'json': js, 'auth': auth}


class KrakenREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='0',
                 url='https://api.kraken.com'):
        super(KrakenREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                         key=key, secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            req = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            req = {}

        req['nonce'] = self.nonce()
        postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(req)

        # Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
        encoded = (str(req['nonce']) + postdata).encode('utf-8')
        message = (endpoint_path.encode('utf-8') +
                   hashlib.sha256(encoded).digest())

        signature = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(self.secret),
                             message, hashlib.sha512)
        sigdigest = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())

        headers = {
            'API-Key': self.key,
            'API-Sign': sigdigest.decode('utf-8')
        }

        return url, {'data': req, 'headers': headers}


class ItbitREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, user_id = '', key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://api.itbit.com'):
        self.userId = user_id
        super(ItbitREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                 key=key, secret=secret)

    def load_key(self, path):
        """
        Load user id, key and secret from file.
        """
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.userId = f.readline().strip()
            self.clientKey = f.readline().strip()
            self.secret = f.readline().strip()

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}

        verb = method_verb

        if verb in ('PUT', 'POST'):
            body = params
        else:
            body = {}

        timestamp = self.nonce()
        nonce = self.nonce()

        message = json.dumps([verb, url, body, nonce, timestamp],
                             separators=(',', ':'))
        sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
        nonced_message = nonce + message
        sha256_hash.update(nonced_message.encode('utf8'))
        hash_digest = sha256_hash.digest()
        hmac_digest = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'),
                               url.encode('utf-8') + hash_digest,
                               hashlib.sha512).digest()
        signature = base64.b64encode(hmac_digest)

        auth_headers = {
            'Authorization': self.key + ':' + signature.decode('utf8'),
            'X-Auth-Timestamp': timestamp,
            'X-Auth-Nonce': nonce,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        return url, {'headers': auth_headers}


class OKCoinREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://www.okcoin.com/api'):
        super(OKCoinREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                         key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self,url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()

        # sig = nonce + url + req
        data = (nonce + url).encode()

        h = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf8'), data, hashlib.sha256)
        signature = h.hexdigest()
        headers = {"ACCESS-KEY":       self.key,
                   "ACCESS-NONCE":     nonce,
                   "ACCESS-SIGNATURE": signature}

        return url, {'headers': headers}


class BTCERest(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='3',
                 url='https://btc-e.com/api'):
        super(BTCERest, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        post_params = params
        post_params.update({'nonce': nonce, 'method': endpoint.split('/', 1)[1]})
        post_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_params)

        signature = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'),
                             post_params.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512)
        headers = {'Key': self.key, 'Sign': signature.hexdigest(),
                   "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

        # split by tapi str to gain clean url;
        url = url.split('/tapi', 1)[0] + '/tapi'

        return url, {'headers': headers, 'params': params}


class CCEXRest(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://c-cex.com/t'):
        super(CCEXRest, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}

        params['apikey'] = self.key
        params['nonce'] = nonce
        post_params = params
        post_params.update({'nonce': nonce, 'method': endpoint})
        post_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_params)

        url = uri + post_params

        sig = hmac.new(url, self.secret, hashlib.sha512)
        headers = {'apisign': sig}

        return url, {'headers': headers}


class CryptopiaREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api'):
        super(CryptopiaREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}


        post_data = json.dumps(params)
        md5 = base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5().updated(post_data).digest())

        sig = self.key + 'POST' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(uri).lower() + nonce + md5
        hmac_sig = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(self.secret),
                                              sig, hashlib.sha256).digest())
        header_data = 'amx' + self.key + ':' + hmac_sig + ':' + nonce
        headers = {'Authorization': header_data,
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

        return uri, {'headers': headers, 'data': post_data}


class GeminiREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://api.gemini.com'):
        super(GeminiREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        payload = params
        payload['nonce'] = nonce
        payload['request'] = endpoint_path
        payload = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload))
        sig = hmac.new(self.secret, payload, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
        headers = {'X-GEMINI-APIKEY': self.key,
                   'X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD': payload,
                   'X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE': sig}
        return uri, {'headers': headers}


class YunbiREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v2',
                 url='https://yunbi.com/api'):
        super(YunbiREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        params['tonce'] = nonce
        params['access_key'] = self.key
        post_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        msg = '%s|%s|%s' % (method_verb, endpoint_path, post_params)

        sig = hmac.new(self.secret, msg, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
        uri += post_params + '&signature=' + sig

        return uri, {}


class RockTradingREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://api.therocktrading.com'):
        super(RockTradingREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                        key=key,
                                        secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        payload = params
        payload['nonce'] = int(nonce)
        payload['request'] = endpoint_path

        msg = nonce + uri
        sig = hmac.new(self.secret.encode(), msg.encode(), hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
        headers = {'X-TRT-APIKEY': self.key,
                   'X-TRT-Nonce': nonce,
                   'X-TRT-SIGNATURE': sig, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        return uri, {'headers': headers}


class PoloniexREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://poloniex.com'):
        super(PoloniexREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                           key=key, secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        params['nonce'] = self.nonce()
        payload = params

        msg = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf-8')
        sig = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'), msg, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
        headers = {'Key': self.key, 'Sign': sig}
        return uri, {'headers': headers, 'data': params}
```

### `bitex.interfaces`

```
>>bitex.interfaces.kraken
"""
https:/kraken.com/help/api
"""

# Import Built-Ins
import logging

# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew
from bitex.api.rest import KrakenREST
from bitex.utils import return_json
from bitex.formatters.kraken import cancel, trade, order_book

# Init Logging Facilities
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Kraken(KrakenREST):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', key_file=''):
        super(Kraken, self).__init__(key, secret)
        if key_file:
            self.load_key(key_file)

    def make_params(self, *pairs, **kwargs):
        q = {'pair': ','.join(pairs)}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return q

    def public_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        path = 'public/' + endpoint
        return self.query('GET', path, **kwargs)

    def private_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        path = 'private/' + endpoint
        return self.query('POST', path, authenticate=True, **kwargs)

    """
    BitEx Standardized Methods
    """

    @return_json(None)
    def ticker(self, *pairs):
        q = self.make_params(*pairs)
        return self.public_query('Ticker', params=q)

    @return_json(order_book)
    def order_book(self, pair, **kwargs):
        q = self.make_params(pair, **kwargs)
        return self.public_query('Depth', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def trades(self, pair, **kwargs):
        q = self.make_params(pair, **kwargs)
        return self.public_query('Trades', params=q)

    def _add_order(self, pair, side, price, amount, **kwargs):
        q = {'pair': pair, 'type': side, 'price': price,
             'ordertype': 'limit', 'volume': amount,
             'trading_agreement': 'agree'}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('AddOrder', params=q)

    @return_json(trade)
    def bid(self, pair, price, amount, **kwargs):
        return self._add_order(pair, 'buy', price, amount, **kwargs)

    @return_json(trade)
    def ask(self, pair, price, amount, **kwargs):
        return self._add_order(pair, 'sell', price, amount, **kwargs)

    @return_json(cancel)
    def cancel_order(self, order_id, **kwargs):
        q = {'txid': order_id}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('CancelOrder', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def order_info(self, *txids, **kwargs):
        if len(txids) > 1:
            q = {'txid': txids}
        elif txids:
            txid, *_ = txids
            q = {'txid': txid}
        else:
            q = {}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('QueryOrders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def balance(self, **kwargs):
        return self.private_query('Balance')

    @return_json(None)
    def withdraw(self, _type, source_wallet, amount, tar_addr, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @return_json(None)
    def deposit_address(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    """
    Exchange Specific Methods
    """

    @return_json(None)
    def time(self):
        return self.public_query('Time')

    @return_json(None)
    def assets(self, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('Assets', params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def pairs(self, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('AssetPairs', params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def ohlc(self, pair, **kwargs):
        q = self.make_params(pair, **kwargs)
        return self.public_query('OHLC', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def spread(self, pair, **kwargs):
        q = self.make_params(pair, **kwargs)
        return self.public_query('Spread', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def orders(self, **kwargs):
        q = kwargs
        return self.private_query('OpenOrders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def closed_orders(self, **kwargs):
        q = kwargs
        return self.private_query('ClosedOrders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def trade_history(self, **kwargs):
        q = kwargs
        return self.private_query('TradesHistory', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def fees(self, pair=None):
        q = {'fee-info': True}

        if pair:
            q['pair'] = pair
        return self.private_query('TradeVolume', params=q)

>>bitex.interfaces.bitfinex
"""
http://docs.bitfinex.com/
"""

# Import Built-Ins
import logging

# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew
from bitex.api.rest import BitfinexREST
from bitex.utils import return_json
from bitex.formatters.bitfinex import trade, cancel, order_status
# Init Logging Facilities
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Bitfinex(BitfinexREST):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', key_file=''):
        super(Bitfinex, self).__init__(key, secret)
        if key_file:
            self.load_key(key_file)

    def public_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        return self.query('GET', endpoint, **kwargs)

    def private_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        return self.query('POST', endpoint, authenticate=True, **kwargs)

    """
    BitEx Standardized Methods
    """
    @return_json(None)
    def order_book(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('book/%s' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def ticker(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('pubticker/%s' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def trades(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('trades/%s' % pair, params=kwargs)

    def _place_order(self, pair, amount, price, side, replace, **kwargs):
        q = {'symbol': pair, 'amount': amount, 'price': price, 'side': side,
             'type': 'exchange limit'}
        q.update(kwargs)
        if replace:
            return self.private_query('order/cancel/replace', params=q)
        else:
            return self.private_query('order/new', params=q)

    @return_json(trade)
    def bid(self, pair, price, amount, replace=False, **kwargs):
        return self._place_order(pair, amount, price, 'buy', replace=replace,
                                 **kwargs)

    @return_json(trade)
    def ask(self, pair, price, amount, replace=False, **kwargs):
        return self._place_order(pair, str(amount), str(price), 'sell',
                                 replace=replace, **kwargs)

    @return_json(cancel)
    def cancel_order(self, order_id, all=False, **kwargs):

        q = {'order_id': int(order_id)}
        q.update(kwargs)
        if not all:
            return self.private_query('order/cancel', params=q)
        else:
            endpoint = 'order/cancel/all'
            return self.private_query(endpoint)

    @return_json(order_status)
    def order(self, order_id, **kwargs):
        q = {'order_id': order_id}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('order/status', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def balance(self, **kwargs):
        return self.private_query('balances', params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def withdraw(self, _type, source_wallet, amount, tar_addr, **kwargs):
        q = {'withdraw_type': _type, 'walletselected': source_wallet,
             'amount': amount, 'address': tar_addr}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('withdraw', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def deposit_address(self, **kwargs):
        q = {'method': currency, 'wallet_name': target_wallet}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('deposit/new', params=kwargs)

    """
    Exchange Specific Methods
    """

    @return_json(None)
    def statistics(self, pair):
        return self.public_query('stats/%s' % pair)

    @return_json(None)
    def funding_book(self, currency, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('lendbook/%s' % currency, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def lends(self, currency, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('lends/%s' % currency, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def pairs(self, details=False):
        if details:
            return self.public_query('symbols_details')
        else:
            return self.public_query('symbols')

    @return_json(None)
    def fees(self):
        return self.private_query('account_infos')

    @return_json(None)
    def orders(self):
        return self.private_query('orders')

    @return_json(None)
    def balance_history(self, currency, **kwargs):
        q = {'currency': currency}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('history/movements', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def trade_history(self, pair, since, **kwargs):
        q = {'symbol': pair, 'timestamp': since}
        q.update(kwargs)
    return self.private_query('mytrades', params=q)

>>bitex.interfaces.gdax
"""
https://docs.gdax.com/
"""

# Import Built-Ins
import logging

# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew
from bitex.api.rest import GDAXRest
from bitex.utils import return_json

# Init Logging Facilities
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class GDAX(GDAXRest):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', key_file=''):
        super(GDAX, self).__init__(key, secret)
        if key_file:
            self.load_key(key_file)

    def public_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        return self.query('GET', endpoint, **kwargs)

    def private_query(self, endpoint, method_verb='POST', **kwargs):
        return self.query(method_verb, endpoint, authenticate=True, **kwargs)

    """
    BitEx Standardized Methods
    """

    @return_json(None)
    def ticker(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/ticker' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def order_book(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/book' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def trades(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/trades' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def bid(self, pair, price, size, **kwargs):
        q = {'side': 'buy', 'type': 'market', 'product_id': pair,
             'price': price, 'size': size}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('orders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def ask(self, pair, price, amount, **kwargs):
        q = {'side': 'sell', 'type': 'market', 'product_id': pair,
             'price': price, 'size': size}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('orders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def cancel_order(self, order_id, all=False, **kwargs):

        if not all:
            return self.private_query('orders/%s' % order_id,
                                      method_verb='DELETE', params=kwargs)
        else:
            return self.private_query('orders', method_verb='DELETE',
                                      params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def order(self, order_id, **kwargs):
        return self.private_query('orders/%s' % order_id, method_verb='GET',
                                  params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def balance(self, **kwargs):
        return self.private_query('accounts', method_verb='GET', params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def withdraw(self, _type, source_wallet, amount, tar_addr, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @return_json(None)
    def deposit_address(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    """
    Exchange Specific Methods
    """

    @return_json
    def time(self):
        return self.public_query('time')

    @return_json(None)
    def currencies(self):
        return self.public_query('currencies')

    @return_json(None)
    def pairs(self):
        return self.public_query('products')

    @return_json(None)
    def ohlc(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/candles' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def stats(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/stats' % pair, params=kwargs)
```

### `bitex.utils`

```
# Import Built-Ins
import logging
import json
import requests
# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew

# Init Logging Facilities
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def return_json(formatter=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                r = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                log.error("return_json(): Error during call to "
                          "%s(%s, %s) %s" % (func.__name__, args, kwargs, e))
                raise

            try:
                r.raise_for_status()
            except requests.HTTPError as e:
                log.error("return_json: HTTPError for url %s: "
                          "%s" % (r.request.url, e))
                return None, r

            try:
                data = r.json()
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                log.error('return_json: Error while parsing json. '
                          'Request url was: %s, result is: '
                          '%s' % (r.request.url, r.text))
                return None, r
            except Exception as e:
                log.error("return_json(): Unexpected error while parsing json "
                          "from %s: %s" % (r.request.url, e))
                raise

            # Apply formatter and return
            if formatter is not None:
                return formatter(data, *args, **kwargs), r
            else:
                return data, r
        return wrapper
return decorator
```

You can also find the code at its GitHub repository. I've omitted some of the interface classes - the three I've provided are about as diverse as they come anyway.

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/bitex/tree/dev) (`dev` branch)

Comment: This has a [follow up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/148983).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot of code here, so I'm just going to review `bitex.utils`. You'll see that there's plenty here for one review. Maybe some of the other reviewers here at Code Review will review some of your other code.

1. There is no module docstring. What is the purpose of this module? What does it contain?
2. `import requests` is in the "Built-Ins" section but as far as I know this module is not built into Python, so it should be in the "Third-Party" section.
3. `return_json` has no docstring. What does it do? What is the meaning of the `formatter` argument? What does it return?
4. It seems to be some kind of decorator for a function that returns a `requests.Response` object that converts it to a function returning two arguments, the first of which is either `None` (if the response was an error, or if the response contained data that could not be decoded as JSON), or the decoded JSON (if the response was successfully decoded and `formatter` is `None`), or the result of `formatter` applied to the decoded JSON and the original arguments to the function (otherwise).

   This seems like a very complicated specification to me, and I think I would find it hard to use, because if you want to pass a `formatter` argument you have to ensure that it takes exactly the same arguments as the function being wrapped, which is not always going to be convenient, surely?

   But maybe you know better, in which case the docstring would be a good place to make the case for the utility of this function, by giving some examples.
5. When writing a decorator, it's a good idea to copy attributes from the original function to the decorated function, so that the latter has the same name, module, docstring and so on as the former. There is a built-in function [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) that you can use to do this.
6. When you log a message, don't use the `%` operator to format the message, instead pass the format string and format arguments separately [as described in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug). (This gives more flexibility to the logger, for example if logging is suppressed then the message may never need to be formatted.)
7. Instead of calling [`Logger.error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.error) and putting the exception into the message, like this:

   ```
   except Exception as e:
       log.error("return_json(): Unexpected error while parsing json "
                 "from %s: %s" % (r.request.url, e))
   ```

   use [`Logger.exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) instead:

   ```
   except Exception:
       log.exception("return_json(): Unexpected error while parsing JSON "
                     "from %s", r.request.url)
   ```

   This adds a traceback to the log.
8. In this code, it looks as if you are using `raise_for_status` to determine if the request succeeded:

   ```
   try:
       r.raise_for_status()
   except requests.HTTPError as e:
       log.error(...)
   ```

   I think it would be simpler just to check the status:

   ```
   if r.status != requests.codes.ok:
       log.error(...)
   ```