# Bitex - Cryptocurrency Exchange API Framework for Python - Round 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, framework, cryptocurrency

This is a follow up to [my previous review request](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148123/bitex-cryptocurrency-exchange-api-framework-for-python).

---

[BitEx](https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/bitex/tree/dev) is a Python module I've been working on for a little over 9 months now, as a side project. It was published 6 months ago on GitHub, and as I edge closer to my 1.0 release, I wanted to take the opportunity to present my code on here, in order to straighten it out.

### What it solves and offers

It's designed to eliminate the need to get into the gory details of REST APIs of crypto exchanges, and offer a homogeneous and intuitive interface for all supported APIs. It takes care of authentication procedures, and offers a standardized set of methods (with identical method signature) for all commonly used methods at an exchange (polling order book and tickers, placing and cancelling orders, amongst others), as well as all other specific methods (or as many as I had the time to implement thus far).

It comes, essentially, as two sub packages: `bitex.api` is the backend taking care of setting up http requests via the `requests` module, as well as handling authentication specifics. It can be seen as wrapper for `requests` and technically could be used all on its own to send and receive data to/from exchanges.

The other is `bitex.interfaces`, which offers the above mentioned homogeneous, standardized methods for all implemented exchanges. In addition to offering identical method signatures, it also aims to standardize method's return values. As these can differ significantly from exchange to exchange, these methods take care of data formatting, via the help of formatters found in `bitex.formatters` and the `return_json` decorator. It relies on `bitex.api`.

### Why I am submitting this for review

Ever since I started this project, I've rewritten the base code several times significantly. It took me a long time to figure out how to lay out the structure (which is mostly due to my learning curve over the past year as a first year software development apprentice).

Over the past two months, however, I've become rather fond and proud of the current structure and deem it quite presentable - enough so, to have it publicly audited.

I have read the meta question on [how to get the best value out of my review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions), and quite initially settled on having three 'rounds' of reviews for my code:

1. Round: [code style](http://Bitex%20-%20Cryptocurrency%20Exchange%20API%20Framework%20for%20Python) (completed), PEP8, readability, pythonic-ness
2. Round: Refactoring options and the evaluation of present layout, especially API class' `sign()` method, `return_json()` decorator and usage of formatter funcs.
3. Round: flaws, improvements in code and logic, bugs, etc.

### Review Round 2: Refactoring and Layout

I have especially my worries about the `bitex.api` sub-module. The `sign()` method is difficult to generalize as it is since the inputs vary massively, forcing me to pass everything to them. I was not able to come up with a more sensible solution.

In `bitex.interfaces`, it at first looked like a good idea to have a `BaseInterface` class, since I have several methods, which appear in all interfaces - `query_public()`, `query_private()`, and the standardized methods. 
At second glimpse, however, this `mixin` class did not make sense.This is because it looks to me like I'd introduce a class for the sake of having a `mixin` class, as I'd have to override methods for most exchanges to some degree anyway, resulting in almost identical code to now - with minimal improvement.

And lastly, the use and design of `bitex.formatters` to format returned data from `bitex.interfaces` classes via the `@return_json` decorator (which may be slightly ill named, by now, since it no longer just returns the `requests.response` JSON value). Is mine an acceptable approach? It seemed like the most straightforward solution (as opposed to cluttering each `Interface` class with the formatting directly).

### `bitex.api`

```
# Import Built-Ins
import logging
import requests
import time
# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class RESTAPI:

    def __init__(self, uri, api_version='', key='', secret=''):
        """
        Base Class for REST API connections.
        """
        self.key = key
        self.secret = secret
        self.uri = uri
        self.apiversion = api_version
        self.req_methods = {'POST': requests.post, 'PUT': requests.put,
                            'GET': requests.get, 'DELETE': requests.delete,
                            'PATCH': requests.patch}
        log.debug("Initialized RESTAPI for URI: %s; "
                  "Will request on API version: %s" %
                  (self.uri, self.apiversion))

    def load_key(self, path):
        """
        Load key and secret from file.
        """
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.key = f.readline().strip()
            self.secret = f.readline().strip()

    def nonce(self):
        return str(int(1000 * time.time()))

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Dummy Signature creation method. Override this in child.
        URL is required to be returned, as some Signatures use the url for
        sig generation, and api calls made must match the address exactly.
        """
        url = self.uri

        return url, {'params': {'test_param': "authenticated_chimichanga"}}

    def query(self, method_verb, endpoint, authenticate=False,
              *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Queries exchange using given data. Defaults to unauthenticated query.
        """
        request_method = self.req_methods[method_verb]

        if self.apiversion:
            endpoint_path = '/' + self.apiversion + '/' + endpoint
        else:
            endpoint_path = '/' + endpoint

        url = self.uri + endpoint_path
        if authenticate:  # sign off kwargs and url before sending request
            url, request_kwargs = self.sign(url, endpoint, endpoint_path,
                                            method_verb, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            request_kwargs = kwargs
        log.debug("Making request to: %s, kwargs: %s" % (url, request_kwargs))
        r = request_method(url, timeout=5, **request_kwargs)
        log.debug("Made %s request made to %s, with headers %s and body %s. "
                  "Status code %s" %
                  (r.request.method, r.request.url, r.request.headers,
                   r.request.body, r.status_code))
        return r
```

#### `bitex.api.rest`

```
# Import Built-ins
import logging
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import time
import urllib
import urllib.parse
from requests.auth import AuthBase

# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew
from bitex.api.api import RESTAPI


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class BitfinexREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://api.bitfinex.com'):
        super(BitfinexREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                           key=key, secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            req = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            req = {}
        req['request'] = endpoint_path
        req['nonce'] = self.nonce()

        js = json.dumps(req)
        data = base64.standard_b64encode(js.encode('utf8'))

        h = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf8'), data, hashlib.sha384)
        signature = h.hexdigest()
        headers = {"X-BFX-APIKEY": self.key,
                   "X-BFX-SIGNATURE": signature,
                   "X-BFX-PAYLOAD": data}

        return url, {'headers': headers}


class BitstampREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, user_id='', key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://www.bitstamp.net/api'):
        self.id = user_id
        super(BitstampREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                           key=key, secret=secret)

    def load_key(self, path):
        """
        Load key and secret from file.
        """
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.id = f.readline().strip()
            self.key = f.readline().strip()
            self.secret = f.readline().strip()

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        message = nonce + self.id + self.key

        signature = hmac.new(self.secret.encode(), message.encode(),
                             hashlib.sha256)
        signature = signature.hexdigest().upper()

        try:
            req = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            req = {}
        req['key'] = self.key
        req['nonce'] = nonce
        req['signature'] = signature
        return url, {'data': req}


class BittrexREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1.1',
                 url='https://bittrex.com/api'):
        super(BittrexREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                          secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}

        nonce = self.nonce()

        req_string = endpoint_path + '?apikey=' + self.key + "&nonce=" + nonce + '&'
        req_string += urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        headers = {"apisign": hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'),
                                       (self.uri + req_string).encode('utf-8'),
                                       hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()}

        return self.uri + req_string, {'headers': headers, 'params': {}}


class CoincheckREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='api',
                 url='https://coincheck.com'):
        super(CoincheckREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                            key=key, secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):

        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}

        params = json.dumps(params)
        # sig = nonce + url + req
        data = (nonce + endpoint_path + params).encode('utf-8')
        h = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf8'), data, hashlib.sha256)
        signature = h.hexdigest()
        headers = {"ACCESS-KEY": self.key,
                   "ACCESS-NONCE": nonce,
                   "ACCESS-SIGNATURE": signature}

        return url, {'headers': headers}


class GdaxAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key, passphrase):
        self.api_key = api_key.encode('utf-8')
        self.secret_key = secret_key.encode('utf-8')
        self.passphrase = passphrase.encode('utf-8')

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        message = (timestamp + request.method + request.path_url +
                   (request.body or ''))
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
        signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())

        request.headers.update({
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
            'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
        return request


class GDAXRest(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, passphrase='', key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://api.gdax.com'):
        self.passphrase = passphrase
        super(GDAXRest, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                       secret=secret)

    def load_key(self, path):
        """
        Load key and secret from file.
        """
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.passphrase = f.readline().strip()
            self.key = f.readline().strip()
            self.secret = f.readline().strip()

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        auth = GdaxAuth(self.key, self.secret, self.passphrase)
        try:
            js = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            js = {}

        return url, {'json': js, 'auth': auth}


class KrakenREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='0',
                 url='https://api.kraken.com'):
        super(KrakenREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                         key=key, secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            req = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            req = {}

        req['nonce'] = self.nonce()
        postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode(req)

        # Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
        encoded = (str(req['nonce']) + postdata).encode('utf-8')
        message = (endpoint_path.encode('utf-8') +
                   hashlib.sha256(encoded).digest())

        signature = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(self.secret),
                             message, hashlib.sha512)
        sigdigest = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())

        headers = {
            'API-Key': self.key,
            'API-Sign': sigdigest.decode('utf-8')
        }

        return url, {'data': req, 'headers': headers}


class ItbitREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, user_id = '', key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://api.itbit.com'):
        self.userId = user_id
        super(ItbitREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                 key=key, secret=secret)

    def load_key(self, path):
        """
        Load user id, key and secret from file.
        """
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            self.userId = f.readline().strip()
            self.clientKey = f.readline().strip()
            self.secret = f.readline().strip()

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}

        verb = method_verb

        if verb in ('PUT', 'POST'):
            body = params
        else:
            body = {}

        timestamp = self.nonce()
        nonce = self.nonce()

        message = json.dumps([verb, url, body, nonce, timestamp],
                             separators=(',', ':'))
        sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256()
        nonced_message = nonce + message
        sha256_hash.update(nonced_message.encode('utf8'))
        hash_digest = sha256_hash.digest()
        hmac_digest = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'),
                               url.encode('utf-8') + hash_digest,
                               hashlib.sha512).digest()
        signature = base64.b64encode(hmac_digest)

        auth_headers = {
            'Authorization': self.key + ':' + signature.decode('utf8'),
            'X-Auth-Timestamp': timestamp,
            'X-Auth-Nonce': nonce,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        return url, {'headers': auth_headers}


class OKCoinREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://www.okcoin.com/api'):
        super(OKCoinREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                         key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self,url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()

        # sig = nonce + url + req
        data = (nonce + url).encode()

        h = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf8'), data, hashlib.sha256)
        signature = h.hexdigest()
        headers = {"ACCESS-KEY":       self.key,
                   "ACCESS-NONCE":     nonce,
                   "ACCESS-SIGNATURE": signature}

        return url, {'headers': headers}


class BTCERest(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='3',
                 url='https://btc-e.com/api'):
        super(BTCERest, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, url, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        post_params = params
        post_params.update({'nonce': nonce, 'method': endpoint.split('/', 1)[1]})
        post_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_params)

        signature = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'),
                             post_params.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512)
        headers = {'Key': self.key, 'Sign': signature.hexdigest(),
                   "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

        # split by tapi str to gain clean url;
        url = url.split('/tapi', 1)[0] + '/tapi'

        return url, {'headers': headers, 'params': params}


class CCEXRest(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://c-cex.com/t'):
        super(CCEXRest, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}

        params['apikey'] = self.key
        params['nonce'] = nonce
        post_params = params
        post_params.update({'nonce': nonce, 'method': endpoint})
        post_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_params)

        url = uri + post_params

        sig = hmac.new(url, self.secret, hashlib.sha512)
        headers = {'apisign': sig}

        return url, {'headers': headers}


class CryptopiaREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api'):
        super(CryptopiaREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}


        post_data = json.dumps(params)
        md5 = base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5().updated(post_data).digest())

        sig = self.key + 'POST' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(uri).lower() + nonce + md5
        hmac_sig = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(self.secret),
                                              sig, hashlib.sha256).digest())
        header_data = 'amx' + self.key + ':' + hmac_sig + ':' + nonce
        headers = {'Authorization': header_data,
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}

        return uri, {'headers': headers, 'data': post_data}


class GeminiREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://api.gemini.com'):
        super(GeminiREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        payload = params
        payload['nonce'] = nonce
        payload['request'] = endpoint_path
        payload = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload))
        sig = hmac.new(self.secret, payload, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
        headers = {'X-GEMINI-APIKEY': self.key,
                   'X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD': payload,
                   'X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE': sig}
        return uri, {'headers': headers}


class YunbiREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v2',
                 url='https://yunbi.com/api'):
        super(YunbiREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version, key=key,
                                         secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        params['tonce'] = nonce
        params['access_key'] = self.key
        post_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
        msg = '%s|%s|%s' % (method_verb, endpoint_path, post_params)

        sig = hmac.new(self.secret, msg, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
        uri += post_params + '&signature=' + sig

        return uri, {}


class RockTradingREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='v1',
                 url='https://api.therocktrading.com'):
        super(RockTradingREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                        key=key,
                                        secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        nonce = self.nonce()
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        payload = params
        payload['nonce'] = int(nonce)
        payload['request'] = endpoint_path

        msg = nonce + uri
        sig = hmac.new(self.secret.encode(), msg.encode(), hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
        headers = {'X-TRT-APIKEY': self.key,
                   'X-TRT-Nonce': nonce,
                   'X-TRT-SIGNATURE': sig, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        return uri, {'headers': headers}


class PoloniexREST(RESTAPI):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', api_version='',
                 url='https://poloniex.com'):
        super(PoloniexREST, self).__init__(url, api_version=api_version,
                                           key=key, secret=secret)

    def sign(self, uri, endpoint, endpoint_path, method_verb, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            params = kwargs['params']
        except KeyError:
            params = {}
        params['nonce'] = self.nonce()
        payload = params

        msg = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf-8')
        sig = hmac.new(self.secret.encode('utf-8'), msg, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
        headers = {'Key': self.key, 'Sign': sig}
        return uri, {'headers': headers, 'data': params}
```

### `bitex.interfaces`

#### `bitex.interfaces.kraken`

```
"""
https:/kraken.com/help/api
"""

# Import Built-Ins
import logging

# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew
from bitex.api.rest import KrakenREST
from bitex.utils import return_json
from bitex.formatters.kraken import cancel, trade, order_book

# Init Logging Facilities
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Kraken(KrakenREST):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', key_file=''):
        super(Kraken, self).__init__(key, secret)
        if key_file:
            self.load_key(key_file)

    def make_params(self, *pairs, **kwargs):
        q = {'pair': ','.join(pairs)}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return q

    def public_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        path = 'public/' + endpoint
        return self.query('GET', path, **kwargs)

    def private_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        path = 'private/' + endpoint
        return self.query('POST', path, authenticate=True, **kwargs)

    """
    BitEx Standardized Methods
    """

    @return_json(None)
    def ticker(self, *pairs):
        q = self.make_params(*pairs)
        return self.public_query('Ticker', params=q)

    @return_json(order_book)
    def order_book(self, pair, **kwargs):
        q = self.make_params(pair, **kwargs)
        return self.public_query('Depth', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def trades(self, pair, **kwargs):
        q = self.make_params(pair, **kwargs)
        return self.public_query('Trades', params=q)

    def _add_order(self, pair, side, price, amount, **kwargs):
        q = {'pair': pair, 'type': side, 'price': price,
             'ordertype': 'limit', 'volume': amount,
             'trading_agreement': 'agree'}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('AddOrder', params=q)

    @return_json(trade)
    def bid(self, pair, price, amount, **kwargs):
        return self._add_order(pair, 'buy', price, amount, **kwargs)

    @return_json(trade)
    def ask(self, pair, price, amount, **kwargs):
        return self._add_order(pair, 'sell', price, amount, **kwargs)

    @return_json(cancel)
    def cancel_order(self, order_id, **kwargs):
        q = {'txid': order_id}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('CancelOrder', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def order_info(self, *txids, **kwargs):
        if len(txids) > 1:
            q = {'txid': txids}
        elif txids:
            txid, *_ = txids
            q = {'txid': txid}
        else:
            q = {}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('QueryOrders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def balance(self, **kwargs):
        return self.private_query('Balance')

    @return_json(None)
    def withdraw(self, _type, source_wallet, amount, tar_addr, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @return_json(None)
    def deposit_address(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    """
    Exchange Specific Methods
    """

    @return_json(None)
    def time(self):
        return self.public_query('Time')

    @return_json(None)
    def assets(self, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('Assets', params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def pairs(self, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('AssetPairs', params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def ohlc(self, pair, **kwargs):
        q = self.make_params(pair, **kwargs)
        return self.public_query('OHLC', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def spread(self, pair, **kwargs):
        q = self.make_params(pair, **kwargs)
        return self.public_query('Spread', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def orders(self, **kwargs):
        q = kwargs
        return self.private_query('OpenOrders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def closed_orders(self, **kwargs):
        q = kwargs
        return self.private_query('ClosedOrders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def trade_history(self, **kwargs):
        q = kwargs
        return self.private_query('TradesHistory', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def fees(self, pair=None):
        q = {'fee-info': True}

        if pair:
            q['pair'] = pair
        return self.private_query('TradeVolume', params=q)
```

#### `bitex.interfaces.bitfinex`

```
"""
http://docs.bitfinex.com/
"""

# Import Built-Ins
import logging

# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew
from bitex.api.rest import BitfinexREST
from bitex.utils import return_json
from bitex.formatters.bitfinex import trade, cancel, order_status
# Init Logging Facilities
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Bitfinex(BitfinexREST):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', key_file=''):
        super(Bitfinex, self).__init__(key, secret)
        if key_file:
            self.load_key(key_file)

    def public_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        return self.query('GET', endpoint, **kwargs)

    def private_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        return self.query('POST', endpoint, authenticate=True, **kwargs)

    """
    BitEx Standardized Methods
    """
    @return_json(None)
    def order_book(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('book/%s' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def ticker(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('pubticker/%s' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def trades(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('trades/%s' % pair, params=kwargs)

    def _place_order(self, pair, amount, price, side, replace, **kwargs):
        q = {'symbol': pair, 'amount': amount, 'price': price, 'side': side,
             'type': 'exchange limit'}
        q.update(kwargs)
        if replace:
            return self.private_query('order/cancel/replace', params=q)
        else:
            return self.private_query('order/new', params=q)

    @return_json(trade)
    def bid(self, pair, price, amount, replace=False, **kwargs):
        return self._place_order(pair, amount, price, 'buy', replace=replace,
                                 **kwargs)

    @return_json(trade)
    def ask(self, pair, price, amount, replace=False, **kwargs):
        return self._place_order(pair, str(amount), str(price), 'sell',
                                 replace=replace, **kwargs)

    @return_json(cancel)
    def cancel_order(self, order_id, all=False, **kwargs):

        q = {'order_id': int(order_id)}
        q.update(kwargs)
        if not all:
            return self.private_query('order/cancel', params=q)
        else:
            endpoint = 'order/cancel/all'
            return self.private_query(endpoint)

    @return_json(order_status)
    def order(self, order_id, **kwargs):
        q = {'order_id': order_id}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('order/status', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def balance(self, **kwargs):
        return self.private_query('balances', params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def withdraw(self, _type, source_wallet, amount, tar_addr, **kwargs):
        q = {'withdraw_type': _type, 'walletselected': source_wallet,
             'amount': amount, 'address': tar_addr}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('withdraw', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def deposit_address(self, **kwargs):
        q = {'method': currency, 'wallet_name': target_wallet}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('deposit/new', params=kwargs)

    """
    Exchange Specific Methods
    """

    @return_json(None)
    def statistics(self, pair):
        return self.public_query('stats/%s' % pair)

    @return_json(None)
    def funding_book(self, currency, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('lendbook/%s' % currency, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def lends(self, currency, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('lends/%s' % currency, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def pairs(self, details=False):
        if details:
            return self.public_query('symbols_details')
        else:
            return self.public_query('symbols')

    @return_json(None)
    def fees(self):
        return self.private_query('account_infos')

    @return_json(None)
    def orders(self):
        return self.private_query('orders')

    @return_json(None)
    def balance_history(self, currency, **kwargs):
        q = {'currency': currency}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('history/movements', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def trade_history(self, pair, since, **kwargs):
        q = {'symbol': pair, 'timestamp': since}
        q.update(kwargs)
    return self.private_query('mytrades', params=q)
```

#### `bitex.interfaces.gdax`

```
"""
https://docs.gdax.com/
"""

# Import Built-Ins
import logging

# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew
from bitex.api.rest import GDAXRest
from bitex.utils import return_json

# Init Logging Facilities
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class GDAX(GDAXRest):
    def __init__(self, key='', secret='', key_file=''):
        super(GDAX, self).__init__(key, secret)
        if key_file:
            self.load_key(key_file)

    def public_query(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        return self.query('GET', endpoint, **kwargs)

    def private_query(self, endpoint, method_verb='POST', **kwargs):
        return self.query(method_verb, endpoint, authenticate=True, **kwargs)

    """
    BitEx Standardized Methods
    """

    @return_json(None)
    def ticker(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/ticker' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def order_book(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/book' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def trades(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/trades' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def bid(self, pair, price, size, **kwargs):
        q = {'side': 'buy', 'type': 'market', 'product_id': pair,
             'price': price, 'size': size}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('orders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def ask(self, pair, price, amount, **kwargs):
        q = {'side': 'sell', 'type': 'market', 'product_id': pair,
             'price': price, 'size': size}
        q.update(kwargs)
        return self.private_query('orders', params=q)

    @return_json(None)
    def cancel_order(self, order_id, all=False, **kwargs):

        if not all:
            return self.private_query('orders/%s' % order_id,
                                      method_verb='DELETE', params=kwargs)
        else:
            return self.private_query('orders', method_verb='DELETE',
                                      params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def order(self, order_id, **kwargs):
        return self.private_query('orders/%s' % order_id, method_verb='GET',
                                  params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def balance(self, **kwargs):
        return self.private_query('accounts', method_verb='GET', params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def withdraw(self, _type, source_wallet, amount, tar_addr, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @return_json(None)
    def deposit_address(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    """
    Exchange Specific Methods
    """

    @return_json
    def time(self):
        return self.public_query('time')

    @return_json(None)
    def currencies(self):
        return self.public_query('currencies')

    @return_json(None)
    def pairs(self):
        return self.public_query('products')

    @return_json(None)
    def ohlc(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/candles' % pair, params=kwargs)

    @return_json(None)
    def stats(self, pair, **kwargs):
        return self.public_query('products/%s/stats' % pair, params=kwargs)
```

### `bitex.utils`

```
# Import Built-Ins
import logging
import json
import requests
# Import Third-Party

# Import Homebrew

# Init Logging Facilities
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def return_json(formatter=None):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                r = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                log.error("return_json(): Error during call to "
                          "%s(%s, %s) %s" % (func.__name__, args, kwargs, e))
                raise

            try:
                r.raise_for_status()
            except requests.HTTPError as e:
                log.error("return_json: HTTPError for url %s: "
                          "%s" % (r.request.url, e))
                return None, r

            try:
                data = r.json()
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                log.error('return_json: Error while parsing json. '
                          'Request url was: %s, result is: '
                          '%s' % (r.request.url, r.text))
                return None, r
            except Exception as e:
                log.error("return_json(): Unexpected error while parsing json "
                          "from %s: %s" % (r.request.url, e))
                raise

            # Apply formatter and return
            if formatter is not None:
                return formatter(data, *args, **kwargs), r
            else:
                return data, r
        return wrapper
return decorator
```

You can also find the code at its GitHub repository. I've omitted some of the interface classes - the three I've provided are about as diverse as they come anyway.

[GitHub Repository](https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/bitex/tree/dev) (`dev` branch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a lot of code here, so I'm just going to review `bitex.api`. You'll see that there's plenty here for one review. Maybe some of the other reviewers here at Code Review will review some of your other code.

1. There is no module docstring. What is the purpose of this module? What does it contain?
2. `import requests` is in the "Built-Ins" section but as far as I know this module is not built into Python, so it should be in the "Third-Party" section.
3. The name `RESTAPI` could be improved. Does an instance of this class represent an API client or an API server? The name does not make it clear.
4. The `RESTAPI` class has no docstring. What does an instance of this class represent? Can you give some examples of how it might be used? There is text in your introduction to the post that could be used as a starting point for the docstring.
5. When you log a message, don't use the `%` operator to format the message, instead pass the format string and format arguments separately [as described in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.debug). (This gives more flexibility to the logger, for example if logging is suppressed then the message may never need to be formatted.)
6. The docstring for the `__init__` method needs to document that method, not the whole class. So it should start "Create a RESTAPI object ..." and go on to document the meaning of the arguments.
7. It's very minor, but why is the argument spelled `api_version` with an underscore, but the attribute spelled `apiversion` without?
8. It is risky to have default arguments for `key` and `secret` that are insecure. There is a risk that due to an oversight, the `load_key` method may not get called (especially since there does not appear to be documentation explaining when you need to call it). This would leave the API insecure. It is much better if code can be secure by default. So I would have prefer to have default arguments that are invalid.
9. `self.req_methods` is the same every time, so it should be a global constant or a class attribute, not an instance attribute.
10. The repetition in the construction of `self.req_methods` could be avoided, for example:

    ```
    # Supported HTTP verbs.
    VERBS = 'DELETE GET PATCH POST PUT'.split()
    REQ_METHODS = {verb: getattr(requests, verb.lower()) for verb in VERBS}
    ```

    But actually I think that these data structures are unnecessary. Instead of:

    ```
    request_method = self.req_methods[method_verb]
    # ...
    r = request_method(url, timeout=5, **request_kwargs)
    ```

    why not use [`requests.request`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request)?

    ```
    r = requests.request(method_verb, url, timeout=5, **request_kwargs)
    ```
11. The docstring for `load_key` should explain the meaning of the `path` argument. (It is the path to a text file whose first two lines are the key and the secret respectively.)
12. The second argument to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) defaults to `'r'`, so this could be omitted.
13. The method `nonce` has no docstring.
14. Basing a nonce only on the output of [`time.time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) is risky, because this can go backwards:

    ```
    >>> import time
    >>> time.get_clock_info('time').monotonic
    False
    ```

    and that would mean that nonces could repeat.
15. The docstring for `sign` does not explain what the method is supposed to do.
16. The `sign` method is insecure by default. It would be easy to forget to override it, and then nothing would appear to go wrong, but all the signatures would be bogus. It would be better to be secure by default. A good way to do that would be to use the facilities from the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) (Abstract Base Classes) module:

    ```
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

    class RESTAPI(metaclass=ABCMeta):
        # ...
        @abstractmethod
        def sign(self, ...):
            # ...
    ```

    Now any attempt to inherit from `RESTAPI` without overriding the `sign` method will raise an exception.
17. The docstring for the `query` method does not explain what the arguments mean, or what is returned.
18. The `timeout=5` keyword argument is hard-coded. What if someone needs to query an API that needs a longer timeout than this? The value should be a keyword argument to the `query` function (or possibly an attribute of the class or object).